# Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: The given object has a null identifier: com.models.User on hibernate update

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, hql

I am trying to make an update in the database row. I am having this exception

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: The given object has a null identifier: com.models.User
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.getUpdateId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:270)
```

this is my controller code for the submit action from the jsp file

```
// create new user object
            User user = new User();
            user.setName(name);
            user.setEmail(email);
            user.setActive(false);
             _userDao.update(user);
```

this is my dao that defines the update with hibernate session factory utility

```
public void update(User user) {
        getSession().update(user);
    }
```

**//EDITTED:**  this is my mapping for user entity class

```
 @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "userId")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String email;
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private boolean active;
```

I am not able to update the user record where the email address is equal to the one entered in the jsp input form. Kindly assist, this is my first attempt in updating a field with hibernate sessionfactory.

Comment: Provide us mapping for User entity

Comment: Do you mean the model.java class

Comment: `User` class - with mapping used by Hibernate

Comment: I have done that. check to see my edits

Comment: to update an object in hibernate, you must load it first, then you can update it.

Comment: Yes. I am doing that. I am loading it first using a select query

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that you are using `update` method on not existing entity. If you want to save newly created entity you have to use `save` or `saveOrUpdate`.

`update` method works only if entity already exists in DB.

Comment: Yeah. the entity already exists in the db. Probably should I say I am missing the where clause in my dao

Comment: Nope, you didnt set primary key -> if user exist in DB you have to set same ID in you entity as in db

Comment: I am aiming to update an entity I am not creating a new one

Comment: update record where email in the database is equal to the email in the jsp input type

Comment: But - if you want to update existing entity it must have property which can define it in DB - in you case primary key.

Comment: Provide more code or query or something with we can work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the slimier situation at my work. As @ByeBye said the problem was trying to update an entity which was not persisted before. See following example

```
SalesOrder salesOrder = consignment.getSalesOrder();
    if (salesOrder != null) {
       // some code
    } 
    else{
        // 
        salesOrder = new SalesOrder();
        consignment.setSalesOrder(salesOrder);
    }
    salesOrderRepository.update(salesOrder); // hibernate update
    return salesOrder;
}
Here when the execution of code comes to else part. It try to create a new sales order object (where the object id is null ) and try to update it. And this cause the mentioned error.
```

So my fix was simply changing the update to saveOrUpdate . see below

```
        .......
        salesOrder = new SalesOrder();
        consignment.setSalesOrder(salesOrder);
    }
    salesOrderRepository.saveOrUpdate(salesOrder);
    return salesOrder;
}
```

So then it commands hibernate to first persist the non-existing objects and then do all the updates upon that (if required ).

Hope this scenario will help to all